# get_osm function in osmar (R) gives SSL error

Tags: r, osmar

Since a couple of months ago the following code run errorless

```
   library(osmar)
   src <- osmsource_api(url = "https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/")
   bb <- corner_bbox(13.3,40.79,13.5,40.81)
   ua <- get_osm(bb, source = src)
```

now it gives me the following error

"Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version"

I failed to understand the issue.
I try to run the code using two other computers with different version (older) of R but it still doesn't work.

Anyone has a possible solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. In detail the OSMAR package uses the package *RCurl* to load content which uses somehow an old encryption standard.
You can fix the problem by building your "own" OSMAR package with small modifications.

- downloading the original package source from CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osmar/index.html
- unpack it
- create a R project file in the folder *osmar*, e.g. by using RStudio and click new project
- go to the *NAMESPACE* file and add the line

```
import(curl)
```

- add the package in the file R\get.R

```
#' @import RCurl
#' @import XML
#' @import gtools
#' @import methods
#' @import Curl
```

- and exhange the method *getURL* from *RCurl* with the method *curl* from the package *curl*

```
get_osm_data.api <- function(source, what, ...) {
  request <- osm_request(source, what, ...)
  #response <- getURL(request, .encoding = "UTF-8")
  response <- paste(readLines(curl::curl(request)), collapse = "")
}
```

- finally you can build the package. Restart RStudio / your R environment to use it.

This helped in my case.
Best Andreas Weigert